# how to convert date format in Angular Js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am getting the

```
 last_login:"Thu, 09 Oct 2014 16:59:12 +0530" ,
```

In JSON data and I want to display it like "Oct,09". How to achieve this in AngularJS?

Can we do this using date filter ? 
If Yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can we do this using date filter ?*

You can use [date-filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) like

In HTML Template Binding

```
{{ dateVariable| date : "MMM, dd"}}
```

In JavaScript

```
$filter('date')(dateVariable, "MMM, dd", timezone)
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. but I am getting the value in string. Does your first solution work even if any kind of value is coming like string?

Comment: @ShivekParmar, You can simply convert your string variable to date like `new Date(last_login)`, Then above will surely work.

Comment: does your second solution work if I use it inside html or I have to use it inside controller.?

Comment: @ShivekParmar, Seconds should be used in Controller not inside HTML.

Answer (score 2):

create a custom filter

```
app.filter('dateToISO', function() {
  return function(input) {
    input = new Date(input).toISOString();
    return input;
 };
```

call that custome filter to get the date in ISO format and format into desire format
[angular api for date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```
<div>
    {{"Thu, 09 Oct 2014 16:59:12 +0530" | dateToISO | date:'MMM, yyyy'}}  // filter date using
</div>
```